# How to add a selected image into imread() function in opencv2

Tags: python, opencv

I want to pick a random image from the desktop and pass that image into imread() function. Currently, I have added a predefined image into imread(). How can I enter a randomly selected image into that function?

```
img = cv2.imread("floor_plan_02.png", 0)
```

Comment: You get the paths of all the images in a specific folder and pick one of them randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running with the Desktop as your current directory, it is as simple as this:

```
import random
from glob import glob

# Get name of a random PNG file
filename = random.choice(glob('*.png'))
```

---

If you are running with a different current directory, you can simply change directory to the desktop first. Or you can use the rather nice `pathlib` to load a random PNG from your Desktop:

```
from pathlib import Path
import random
import cv2

# Choose random filename from all PNG files on Desktop
filename = random.choice( list((Path.home() / 'Desktop').glob('*.png')) )

# Open that file with OpenCV
im = cv2.imread(str(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use `glob` and `numpy`

The code below will search your directory for `png` images & put them in a `list` called `img_files`. Then using `numpy.random.randint()` an index for an image in the list of images is chosen at random.

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read in all *.png file names
img_files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    img_files.append(file)
    
print(img_files)

# Choose an image at random & read it in
random_image = img_files[np.random.randint(0, len(img_files))]
print(random_image)
img = cv2.imread(random_image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Display image
cv2.namedWindow("Random image")
cv2.imshow("Random image", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```